# Nginx block access to sub directory when sub directory name is unknown

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to setup Nginx to show files in a public folder for a user. The site will have multiple users and each user has a sub directory which the name is unknown to Nginx.

Example Directory Structure:

```
/users/usernameHere/public
/users/usernameHere/private
```

I only want nginx to show files from the users public directory and deny all access to any other directories.

This is what I tried so far:

```
location ^~ /users/*/public/ {
    allow all;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ^~ /users/ {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: There might be a problem with your first location regex, should be ``/users/.*/public/``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this config

```
location ~ /users/.*/public/ {
    allow all;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /users/ {
    deny all;
}
```

Read the [official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to see difference between the modifier before the uri, You first location is a regular expression location and should use `~` or `*~` for case-sensitive and case-insensitive matches.

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression. Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching).

Then your second location is a common location defined by a prefix string `/users/`, the modifier `^~` you use means skip the regular expression check and use the current longest matching prefix, here is the `/users/` one, so with your config you will always get a 403 return.

> If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.